# How come my array is only saving the last number I entered?

Tags: java, arrays, input

My code is:

```
int total = 10;
int[] myArray = new int [total];

System.out.println("Enter numbers.  To stop, enter 0.")

int numbers = input.nextInt();

while (numbers != 0) {
     for (int i = 0; i < total; i ++)
          myArray[i] = numbers;

     numbers = input.nextInt();
}

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
     System.out.print(myArray[i] + ", ") //This line only prints the last number I enter 10 times.
```

I want to be able to print the whole array with the numbers I entered.  For example:

I enter:  `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0`

But the result I get is:  `10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10`

EDIT:  I don't get why my question has been marked a duplicate?  I tried searching everywhere on this site for a similar question and haven't found one so that's why I asked.  Isn't this the purpose of this site?

EDIT 2:  Fine.  I see how it is.  I'll take my questions to some other more helpful sites.  Thank you for your "service" Stack Exchange.

Comment: What do you think your for loop does?

Comment: From your code, what I understand, you're probably trying take inputs until user enters `0`, or your array is filled up? Am I right?

Comment: +Muhammad  Yes.  That's what I'm trying for.

Comment: I've answered your question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is resetting all of the items in the array each time. I doubt that you meant to do that.

Comment: I see.  But if I take out the input line in the while loop, how will I be able to stop the looping when the user enters a `0`?

Comment: numbers != 0 on your while loop is correct, you just have to remove the for loop inside the while loop and add another condition that will check if user has already filled all the arrays. something like while (numbers != 0 || counter < total)

Then ofcourse you have to assign the input into your array and update the counter

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Declare `i` outside `while` loop and initialize it with `0`.
2. Change the `while` loop's condition to `numbers != 0 && i < total`.
3. Remove the `for` loop inside your `while` loop.
4. Instead just write `myArray[i] = numbers;` and `i++;` to replace the `for` loop.

Here's the code:

```
int numbers = input.nextInt();
int i = 0;
while (numbers != 0 && i < total) {
    myArray[i] = numbers;
    i++;
    numbers = input.nextInt();
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/tg8eEd)'s your code working fine.